# Why can one say (got this out of some lyrics): "I am the dangers that never sleeps"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, lyrics

Maybe it's because my native language is Dutch. I heard this sentence sung: "I am the dangers that never sleeps".

[image]

This sounds very strange to me. Shouldn't it be:

> -I am the danger that never sleeps
> -I am the dangers that never sleep

It seems that the line I cited is a combination of the two. Or is this just a manner of speaking (like "He don't")?

The line is from a great song [I am the virus](https://www.google.com/search?q=lyrics%20i%20am%20the%20virus%20killing%20joke&rlz=1C1NDCM_nlNL744NL744&oq=lyrics%20I%20am%20the%20virus&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.15746j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) by [Killing Joke](https://youtu.be/A4wdbibV3IM).

Comment: What song is this line from?

Comment: Possibly "I Am the Virus" by Killing Joke, which has a line shown on Musixmatch as in the OP's title _I am the Hydra-headed beast/
I am the worm you can never delete/
I am the dangers that never sleeps/
I am the virus/
I am the virus/_

Comment: @DescheleSchilder - its a **phial**.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder - I do not know the song, but I do know how to Google for [exact-text match](https://www.google.com/search?source=&q=%22I+am+the+dangers+that+never+sleeps%22) - you surround the text "with quotes like this".

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I think Michael has been "nice" and used google to search for this song for you.  Now you can return the niceness by [edit]ing your question.  Comments are to be deleted. The body of the question should name the song, and provide a useful link.  Thanks.

Comment: .@Lambie I made a link to the song. It's sung and shown at the same time (around 4:26}.

Comment: @Lambie It's a heavy metaller, with two l's. With one l it sounds very different.

Comment: The sound is the same with one or two lls.

Comment: I think it's just wordplay. Which they can do, just for the sake of making it sound horrible, as is the actings in world are...

Comment: @Lambie Doesn't it sound as taler? Or like taller?

Comment: If you say tailer, as in a person who tails another (follow), the ler is fine. Same with metaler. And there is no word play with dangers and sleep.

Comment: I've cut the new question out. If you have a new question about a different song, please ask it in in different question, don't add it to the end here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I am the dangers that never sleeps" is grammatically incorrect.

Either "danger that never sleeps" or "dangers that never sleep" may be correct.

Song lyrics, poems, etc, may not always follow the rules of grammar. This is allowed

Comment: Song lyrics, poems, etc, may not always follow the rules of grammar. This is allowed.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think I accept this as the answer!

Comment: I fail to see how the s adds anything at all to the line. It is just plain ugly, but since it's heavy metal, no one cares. Ugly is good.

Comment: @Lambie The added s make(s) the dangers a single entity. Maybe the ugliness of the world's current state is implied.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder No, it doesn't. It does not sound like that to a native speaker. It just sounds shitty. And none of the rest of the song does anything like that. Therefore, it doesn't work very well. The entire song is built on very hard, short lines with nothing like that in them at all.

Comment: @Lambie Then I really don't know why this is done. I know Jaz Coleman (the singer, who's brother, by the way, is a renowned physicist) is a very well-spoken man who is able to express his thoughts in an excellent way. Although I've seen another mistake in his language in another song. Maybe he just wants us to pay, once and a while, pay attention to this. I mean, if the mistake wasn't made we would not be talking about it.

Comment: ...the singer, **whose** brother...

Comment: Having listened to the song, I think it is just a simple slip of the tongue.   It occurs once,  at the end of a song (and Heavy Metal is tiring to sing) It is quite likely that a singer will make a mistake - it happens all the time to the best of us.  Don't read too much into it.

Comment: I just saw on the TV somebody (an Englishman) saying: **A few of the stones was missing**. That's grammatically incorrect. It's just a way of speaking.

Comment: Regarding the question, I think it's indeed a slip of the tong, after which the lyrics were written down.